# Sending email with Python/Django through Microsoft Exchange (IMAP)

Tags: exchange, smtp, python

I have a Django web application which sends email through a standard SMTP, but I want it to use a mailbox from the corporate Exchange server.

I would like the emails sent from the application to be listed in the sent items of the inbox.

Currently the email are sent, but not listed in the sent items..

Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a copy of the mail into the sent folder on the exchange server, I can think of 2 ways of doing this:

**Exchange Web Services**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx
A quick google reveals a python libraries for doing this, but I've never used them

**IMAP on the Exchange Server**

I wouldn't do this if it's not already enabled, but the python libraries are mature and well documented.